# How to increase the size of the figure by percentage but keep the original aspect ratio?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code to draw a figure

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
import seaborn as sns

decathlon = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Deep-Learning/main/decathlon.txt", sep='\t')

fig = sns.scatterplot(data = decathlon,
                      x = '100m', y = 'Long.jump',
                      hue = 'Points', palette = 'viridis')

sns.regplot(data = decathlon,
            x = '100m', y = 'Long.jump',
            scatter = False)
```

I read answers for similar questions and they use the option `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))`. I would like to keep the original aspect (the ration of width to length), but increase the size of the figure by some percentage for better look.

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

---

I forgot to add a line `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'` in above code. When I add this line below answer unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Hi @BigBen It's not. In that one, the question is "how can one obtain the size of a subplot (axes?) in Matplotlib?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the object returned by `scatterplot()` is an `Axes`, not a figure. `scatterplot()` uses the *current axes* to draw the plot. If there is no *current axes*, then matplotlib automatically creates one in the *current figure*. If there is not *current figure*, then matplotlib automatically creates a new figure.

The size of this figure is determined by the value in `rcParams['figure.figsize']`. Therefore, you should create a figure that has the same aspect ratio as defined in this variable *before* calling your plots.

For instance, the code below creates a figure that's 2x the size of the default figure.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

fig = plt.figure(figsize= 2 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']))
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day")
sns.regplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", scatter=False, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Your answer is so great. It works both for `png` and `svg`.