# Why does not this plot get bigger as expected?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

From a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539392/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-figure-by-percentage-but-keep-the-original-aspec), I got that `plt.figure(figsize = 2 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']))` will increase the plot size by 2 times. With below code, I want to plot 4 subplots in the grid 2x2.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # Change the image format to svg for better quality
don = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Deep-Learning/main/donclassif.txt.gz', sep=';')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2)
plt.figure(figsize = 2 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'])) # This is to have bigger plot

for row in ax:
    for col in row:
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4)
        kmeans.fit(don)
        y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(don)
        col.scatter(don['V1'], don['V2'], c = y_kmeans, cmap = 'viridis') 
        centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
        col.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c = 'red', s = 200, alpha = 0.5);

plt.show()
```

Could you please explain why `plt.figure(figsize = 2 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']))` does not work in this case?

Comment: It could be written as `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=2 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']))`. Just calling `plt.figure` without storing the result creates a dummy new figure, without changing `fig` and without creating the axes on that new figure won't have the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post @JohanC's comment to remove this question from unanswered list.

> It could be written as fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=2 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'])). Just calling plt.figure without storing the result creates a dummy new figure, without changing fig and without creating the axes on that new figure won't have the desired result.